# What does 5%10/2 mean?

Tags: c++

```
5%10/2
```

I know that the `%` sign shows the remainder, so the operation should give `2.5` because the remainder of `5%10` is `5`. So then `5/2` is `2.5`. But it gives me `2`.

Comment: `so the operation should give 2.5` no. You have integer math.

Comment: `5/2` in C and C++ is `2`, because it's integer division. The rest of your logic is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C and C++, there's a difference between **integer** and **floating-point** division. When you divide 2 integer values, you get the result rounded down, so you get 2.5 instead of 2. If you want 2.5, you should cast one of the operands to a float or just use a float/double literal:

```cpp
std::cout << ((double) (5 % 10) / 2) << std::endl; // double cast
std::cout << (5 % 10 / 2.0) << std::endl; // double literal
```

Comment: `2.0` is a `double`, `2.0f` would be a `float`.

Comment: You get 2 instead of 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from integer division.

```
5 % 10 / 2 =
  5    / 2
```

Integer division returns you the floor of the result:

```
5 / 2 = 2.5
floor(2.5) = 2
```

*Floor of the result* means you round the result to the integer value immediatly smaller to the value you obtained (if this value is not already an integer).

```
3 / 2 = 1     (since floor(1.5) = 1)
7 / 3 = 2     (since floor(2.33..) = 2)
10 / 9 = 1    (since floor(1.11..) = 1)
...
```